# Is there a specific word for a humorous device wherein after a reaction, more information changes the meaning of the phrase

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, humor

I found it hard to summarise this in the title, and I thought a few examples would illustrate what I mean best:

> "Well known local celebrities include Alan Bennett and Barry Cryer" (lead up)
>
> <*Audience woo*>
>
> "Wait a minute: Well known local celebrities include Alan Bennett, and Barry Cryer used to know his milkman". (Extra information).
>
> <*Audience laugh*>

---

Another example:

> "'Open fire!', roared the Colonel." (lead up)
>
> <*Gunshot sound effects*> (reaction)
>
> "Yes I do love an open fire, he went on, warming his hands by the blaze" (Extra information, in this case laughing at the expense of whoever's in charge of sound effects).

---

I hope I've made myself clear as to the type of comedy I mean, I'm just wondering whether it has it's own name.

Comment: Both your examples involve ambiguity/mis-direction...

Comment: Variants on this device were famously used by the Two Ronnies.

Comment: That’s called a ... *wait for it....*   ***joke*** ! ;-)

Comment: Yes and doesn't Dan's comment describe all jokes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These could be considered examples of the device called [**paraprosdokian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian):

> A paraprosdokian (/pærəprɒsˈdoʊkiən/) is a figure of speech in which **the latter part of a sentence**, phrase, or larger discourse **is surprising or unexpected in a way that causes the reader or listener to reframe or reinterpret the first part.** It is frequently used for humorous or dramatic effect, sometimes producing an anticlimax. For this reason, it is extremely popular among comedians and satirists.

<sub>(Source - Wikipedia, emphasis mine)</sub>

(I earlier thought these were garden path sentences, but since the trickery here is withheld information, not unusual parsing, this seems a better fit.)

Comment: I was just about to say that the latter part of your answer is better fit, but then got caught up in the humorous affect of examples of paraprosdokian.+1

Comment: @Nikki Yes, those are hilarious. Thanks for the vote of confidence. Seems like editing out the first part was the right choice.

Comment: @TusharRaj Thanks for keeping you edit in parentheses, otherwise I wouldn't have found out about garden path sentences as well as paraprodokians.

Comment: @user3087409: Happy to help. Have fun exploring...